# Stored procedure called through hibernate do not commit changes in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, session

We are developing an application with Spring and hibernate. The dao layer class is as follows :

```
@Autowired
private StoredDao storedDao;

@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public boolean method() throws Exception {

EntityManager em;
Session session;
Transaction tx;

try{

em = emf.createEntityManager();
session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
tx = session.beginTransaction();
...
...
...
storedDao.processBills(billId, billStatus, billApprover);
...
...
tx.commit();
} catch(Exception e){
  tx.rollback();
}

}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Override
    public void processBills(int billId, int billStatus, String billApprover, Session session){

try{

   final Work processBillCaller = buildStoredProcCaller(billId, billStatus, billApprover);

session.doWork(processBillCaller);
} catch (Exception e){

throw new Exception("message");

}

}

private Work buildStoredProcCaller(int billId, int billStatus, String billApprover) {



        return new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {


                    try (CallableStatement callableStmt = con.prepareCall(<procName>);) {

                        callableStmt.setInt(1, billId);
                        callableStmt.setString(2, billStatus);
                        callableStmt.setInt(3, billApprover);


                        callableStmt.executeUpdate();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        throw new SQLException("message");
                    }               

            }
        };

    }
```

All the queries which are in method() they get executed. Also the stored procedure gets executed in method processBills. In the logs, the message is as follows :

[ABC1] [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.SQL] { call  procName ?,?,? }

But the results of the stored procedure are not committed.

There are many session.save() and session.merge() called before and after the stored procedure call. When tx.commit() is executed, everything is commited, except the stored procedure results. No error is coming.

I also tried to comment @Transactional and then running the above code flow. But still, stored procedure code is not getting commited.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: when JPA provides an API for executing stored procs, makes the casual user wonder what you are doing tying your code to some vendor specific code ...

Comment: Hi the other code is in hibernate in other parts of the application. So have to use hibernate for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found the answer to this. Before calling the stored procedure, the new bill is not yet persisted in the database. It gets persisted only when transaction.commit() is called. Hence when the stored procedure was running, the bill to be processed was not in database.

So now before the stored procedure call, now I call session.flush() and then the stored procedure is executed. It works.